# Google Drive Issue

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am working on a google drive file upload Rest API. User gives permissions to my google drive app. Now there is a login-logout system in my application so user can upload files to different accounts.

Technically, I am getting a `"refresh_token"` on user authentication using which I am generating `"access_token"` for each offline request. I have stored `'refresh_token'` in database. When user logout I am removing it from database.

If a user login with `a@gmail.com`, gives permission to my google drive app and logout after upload some files. This user then again try to login with same account, it does not generating "refresh_token" or ask for app permission as it is already given by user.

I want to remove user's app permission on logout. Or I want to get new `"refresh_token"` by new authentication and permission.

Please guide me for this issue.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can Revoking a token https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline or you can just prompt them for a new one

Comment: @DalmTo How to prompt for new refresh_token? Please guide me as I am new with google drive API.

Comment: the same way you got your first refresh token.  Your going to have to ask them to authenticate you again.

Answer (score 0):

How to refresh token?

You'll use $client->refreshToken($refreshToken) like

```
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
$refreshToken = $client->getRefreshToken();
$client->refreshToken($refreshToken);
$newAccessToken = $client->getAccessToken();
$newAccessToken['refresh_token'] = $refreshToken;
file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($newAccessToken));
}
```

Try to check for samples on [google api php library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) on github.